# How to select Order with highest sum of line items price

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables in mysql :
Orders (id, orderName)
Order_item (id, partname, price, order_id)

Order_id in order item is foreign key to Order table.

How to select order with highest sum of order_item price?

can you please advice me how to do it in oracle and mysql?

I try to do it with this query:

```
SELECT ord.* FROM ORDERS ord WHERE ID =  (Select  o.id from  ORDERS o
inner join order_item oi on o.id =oi.order_id
group by oi.id,ord.orderName
order by sum(oi.price) desc limit 1)
```

but it select order with highest price of order_item.price.

;

Note that select top 1 is not valid statement in mysql.

Is this correct solution ?:

```
SELECT ord.* FROM ORDERS ord WHERE ID =  (  Select  o.id from  ORDERS o
inner join order_item oi on o.id =oi.order_id group by o.id order by sum(oi.price) desc limit 1);
```

At least on Mysql server it runs. How to rewrite this to correct Oracle sql statement?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Note that homework related questions are expected to prove some extra effort.

Comment: It is no homework. I need it to learn myself on sql and rewrite it to JPA criteria api.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data; and the expected output for that sample data.

Comment: Instead of limit, Oracle has `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` - the ANSI SQL way.

Comment: what if there are more than 1 have the same `sum of order_item price`?

Comment: Ok, maybe that is problem. Isnt it solved by MTO comment?

Comment: But limit should select first order, so where is problem?

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle:

```slq
SELECT o.id,
       MAX(o.ordername) AS ordername
FROM   orders o
       INNER JOIN Order_item oi
       ON (o.id = oi.order_id)
GROUP BY o.id
ORDER BY SUM(oi.price) DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

[Oracle fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iVfceRgy)

In MySQL:

```slq
SELECT o.id,
       MAX(o.ordername) AS ordername
FROM   orders o
       INNER JOIN Order_item oi
       ON (o.id = oi.order_id)
GROUP BY o.id
ORDER BY SUM(oi.price) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

[MySQL fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wGYvB0VX)

Comment: But max(o.ordernname) doesnt work. But without it it works!

Comment: @PetrKostroun It does work, see the fiddles linked in the answer.